# Changing the default start location of Google Map - where do I change it?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I manage a listing website where users can add their business to a map - when the address is entered in the correct field the location is automatically shown on the map. However the starting location of the map is Sydney Australia, about 10,000 miles away from the area where the businesses are located. It would be nice to move the location from Sydney to somewhere more appropriate. This function is part of a Wordpress theme and the theme author says that the location can be set via the Google map API, but I can't see where on google maps this is changed. Could someone with more experience point me to where I need to make the change please?

Many thanks.

Comment: What does the code that creates the map look like?   You need to change the `center` in the [MapOptions](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.center) (or call [`setCenter`](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.setCenter) on the map).

Comment: The existing code probably looks something like [this example](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple).

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention your map's initial location is in Sydney, I assume that your map is centered on the lat/lng coordinates provided in Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial):

```
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
```

To change the map's center, replace these coordinates `-34.397, 150.644` with yours.

For example, let's say you are based in London, UK. Get this location's lat/lng (e.g. from [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/London,+UK/@51.5287718,-0.2416789,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99!8m2!3d51.5073509!4d-0.1277583) or the [Geocoder tool](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI)) and then set them to the map's center:

```
center: {lat: 51.507351, lng: -0.127758}
```

You can also do this using `map.setCenter({lat: 51.507351, lng: -0.127758})`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad it helps! Please keep me posted, let me know if you had success on your end.

Comment: Heya @Project-404 if this answer helped you solve your issue please consider accepting it, thank you!